# How to prove this result with sequences and series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

Let $\left(v_n\right)_{n\geqslant1}$ and $\left(w_n\right)_{n\geqslant1}$ be two real sequences with strictly positive values, i.e., $v_n> 0$ and $w_n >0$. Assume that $v_n\sim w_n$ and the series $\sum_k v_k$ diverges.

Hence: $\sum_kv_k\sim\sum_kw_k.$ Which theorem is this? How can we prove it?

Comment: What do you mean with $\sim$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by the relation $\sim$, can you be specific ?

Comment: $a_n \sim b_n \Rightarrow \frac{a_n}{b_n}\rightarrow_{n\rightarrow\infty} 1$

Comment: It's equivallence of functions (at infinity here, hence it should be denoted $\sim_\infty$).

Comment: This results from the Limit Comparison Test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Since $\frac{v_n}{w_n}\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, there is some $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $\frac{v_n}{w_n}<2$.  Then, for all $n>N$, $v_n<2w_n$.  Therefore, $\sum v_n<C+2\sum w_n$.  Therefore, if $\sum w_n$ converges, then so does $\sum v_n$.  You can use a similar argument replacing $2$ with $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: What do you mean with $2_n$? Isn't it $w_n$?

Comment: I changed some notation, but please change it back if I did it incorrectly.